# Check for "real" view behind AnyView

Tags: swiftui

Given the following code

```
import SwiftUI

struct Foo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

let anyViewFoo = AnyView(Foo())

debugPrint(anyViewFoo)
```

Is it possible to check `foo` for the "real" type or e.g. cast to `Foo`? So something (which obviously doesn't work) like the following would be awesome:

```
let foo: Foo? = anyViewFoo as? Foo
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI `AnyView` does not give access to original view, but we can use our custom to store it and then access.

*Note: pay attention - all views are structs, so accessing original view you get **a copy*** (as everywhere in SwiftUI)

Here is a possible approach:

```
struct AnyMyView: View {

    private let internalView: AnyView
    let originalView: Any

    init<V: View>(_ view: V) {
        internalView = AnyView(view)
        originalView = view
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        internalView
    }
}
```

and now a demo of usage based on your original code

```
struct DemoAnyMyView: View {

    let anyViewFoo = AnyMyView(Foo())

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // erased type view
            anyViewFoo

            Divider()

            // restored type view
            if let foo = anyViewFoo.originalView as? Foo {
                foo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Prepared & tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't know if the view is image or text !